# Managing indexes in Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to have custom order to String collection elements in I fetch from Firebase FireStore.

I am quite confused with the documentation with custom indexes and composite indexes.
I have several categories lets say Restaurants, Exits, Shops and I simply want them to be ordered the same way in when I fetch them.
I want to receive Exits then Restaurants then Shops.

In the admin panel, they are not ordered properly and I would like to reorder them. The client code that fetches data is swift code.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore automatically creates single-field indexes for all fields on your documents ([read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes)). That means that simple queries will work straight out of the box.

So a query like this should provide you with the result that you are looking for: *any place sorted by categories in alphabetical order.* And this works because you are only querying one field.

```swift
placesCollectionRef.order(by: "category", descending: false)
```

But often you want to **match** one field and **sort by** another. And in that case you will need a composite index.

```swift
placesCollectionRef
  .whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
  .order(by: "category", descending: false)
```

Firebase is being very helpful in identifying when we need an index. If you do a test run of your app, Firebase will throw an error if there was any query that was missing a necessary index. [The error message will contain a URL that links to your Firebase project console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) and opens a dialog for creating the index.